# IIS 7 URL rewriting from http to https

Tags: iis, redirect, iis-7, web-config, url-rewriting

I have this in my web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I checked that the rule was added in IIS Manager but it doesn't seem to be working.  I have require SSL as off.

So if I go to webvts.mprin.com or http://webvts.mprinc.com, I get 404 not found errors. But if I go to https://webvts.mprinc.com, everything works.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue with my SharePoint web application.  It was an Intranet with an Extranet extension.  The Extranet was only set up for 443.  Once I added a binding on the Extranet application in IIS for port 80, the redirect was successful.